# Display local DOM children relative to mouse position

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to create a polymer element for drawing shapes. This element have a canvas and a paper-dropdown-menu in its local dom. The idea is to draw using mouse on the canvas and once the drawing action is done, the dropdown-menu will show up next to the shape so one can select the name. My main problem here is: how to display the paper-dropdown-menu relative to the mouse position ?

Answer (score 0):

As the user moves their mouse around over an element, the mousemove event is fired. You can listen to these events while the user is "drawing" and keep track of the mouse position:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
var position = document.querySelector('.position');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  position.innerText =
      'client x: ' + e.clientX +
      ' client y: ' + e.clientY;
});
```

```css
.canvas {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas"></div>
<span class="position"></span>
```

The user will somehow stop drawing, and you can use the last mousemove event to figure out where to render the dropdown (via inline absolute positioning). In the following demo, the "dropdown" appears whenever a click occurs inside the canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
var position = document.querySelector('.position');
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

var lastPosition = {x: -100, y: -100};

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  position.innerText =
      'client x: ' + e.clientX +
      ' client y: ' + e.clientY;
  
  lastPosition.x = e.clientX;
  lastPosition.y = e.clientY;
});

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  dropdown.style.left = lastPosition.x + 'px';
  dropdown.style.top = lastPosition.y + 'px';
});
```

```css
.canvas {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas"></div>
<span class="position"></span>
<div class="dropdown"></div>
```